# Get status as null while fetching emails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using request like this:

```
/users/foo@example.com/messages?%24orderBy=createdDateTime&%24skip=6022&%24top=100&%24select=internetMessageId%2CconversationId%2CcreatedDateTime%2CsentDateTime%2ChasAttachments%2Csubject%2Cbody%2CbodyPreview%2CuniqueBody%2Csender%2Cfrom%2CtoRecipients%2CccRecipients%2CbccRecipients%2CisDraft
```

to fetch emails. But I noticed that sometimes the status returned is null but with valid email response. There are also cases that response is empty and status is null. Should the first case have a valid status instead of null?

Comment: Which status is null? The HTTP Response code? Did you try on Graph Explorer? Any chance to get some samples values because currently, it's not easy to understand

Comment: @NicolasR Thanks for your reply. Yeah, HTTP Response code is null. I think our company is using an in house exchange server so I cannot log in to the Graph Explorer. Here is an example I found in our log: https://pastebin.com/8f3CR2Sv. Since the data is sensitive data, I removed body, subject, etc. I also encountered similar issue when fetching attachments. Sometimes the null HTTP response code has valid attachment.