# get null status code fetching attachments

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

This might be the same root cause as the email fetch one: [Get status as null while fetching emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347499/get-status-as-null-while-fetching-emails). But since I haven't got reply on that one, so to ask here. The only difference is this time is fetching attachments.

I am using request like `/me/messages/'.$id.'/attachments` to fetch attachments, but sometimes the status code is null, in my code, I ignore all the null status code and treat them as an invalid response. But in our logs, I found those null status code actually have a valid response and attachments are included in those response. So should I treat null status code as valid? But it looks pretty risky.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your attachment array currently have no values. That's why you are getting null response as follows

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "value": []
}
```

So you should add a new attachment by using the Graph API Post request

```
 POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{{id}}/attachments
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 200

{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment",
  "name": "Holiday event", 
  "item": {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.event",
    "subject": "Discuss gifts for children",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "HTML",
      "content": "Let's look for funding!"
    },
    "start": {
      "dateTime": "2016-12-02T18:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
      "dateTime": "2016-12-02T19:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    }
  }
}
```

Then give a GET request to fetch newly created attachment

```
GET /me/messages/{id}/attachments
```

Also add the application permission Mail.Read

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The attachment actually has valid value. Majority of the time, it has a valid non-null status and valid value. I would say only less than 5% of the time the status is null but in the value field, there is a valid attachment